# How to put a loading.gif image and text while ajax loads the page

Tags: ajax, loading

I am making an ajax call with the following script:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (!session) {
        layoutType = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
          }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            window.location.reload();
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("POST","core/session.php?bW=" + bW,true);
        xmlhttp.send();
    }
}
```

I want to insert a loading image and some text while the pahe loads. How ca I do that?

I want to insert the following image link and text:

```
<img src="cdn/images/ajax-loader.gif" />
<h3>Please wait while we load</h3>
```

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can add an image to the loading are when ajax loads it will basically overwrite your image 
the ajax loader

```
<script>
   var DisplayIMge = document.getElementById("ajaxdiv");
    DisplayIMge.innerHTML = "<img src='cdn/images/ajax-loader.gif' /><h3>Please wait while we load</h3>"
</script>
```

for instance here is the ajax based on the one you are using

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("POST","core/session.php?bW=" + bW,,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Start typing a name in the input field below:</b></p>
<form> 
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" size="20" />
</form>
<p><div id="ajaxdiv"><div></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh hi thanks for the help. Just one more thing. I dont kknow JavaScript / Ajax. Can you  please tell me where to add this code?